# Thread safe field, avoid read write collisions

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, read-write

I'm trying to write synccollection
and I had crashed with read/write problem

I run this code in each thread

```
public void run() {
    for (int j = 0; j < threadElemAmount; j++) {
        list.remove((int) (list.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

And code inside methods size and run

```
public T remove(int index){
    lock.lock();
    if (index >= size || index < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("illegal index value, index = " + index + " size = " + size);
    T removedElement = (T) data[index];
    int movedElementsAmount = size - index - 1;
    //проверить кол-во перемещаемых элементов справа
    if (movedElementsAmount > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(data, index + 1, data, index, movedElementsAmount);
     }
     // очищаем последний
     data[--size] = null;
     lock.unlock();
     return removedElement;    
}
```

and size

```
public int size() {
    lock.lock();
    int result = size;
    lock.unlock();
    return result; 
}
```

I can't use synchronized keyword this is part of special case, just lock, it's almost the same. 
As a result the weakest place it's ulocked space between `list.size()` call and `list.remove()` call. How could I avoid the read/write problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a synchronized function for pop().

remove(index) is a poor replacement for a thread-safe pop function.

also, you should change your code to:

```
lock.lock()
try {
.
.
.
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

In order to make it exception-safe.

Last, but not least, size() doesn't need to be synchronized. Just return the size, since it's a read-only operation. You might want to make the size parameter volatile, but it's not especially necessary here.

Comment: `pop` could refer to removing the first or last element depending on the implementation `Deque` defines a `removeLast()`

Comment: I don't wanna connect just with pop or remove last, what I should I do if I wanna delete each time the element list.size()- 3 for example, or other comprehensive case

Comment: The implement removrFromEnd(int index).

0 will mean the last element,

1 will mean the last but one element,
etc.

Comment: You don't understand connection with end element is bad. just need to connect with index

Comment: And what if I want to use removeFromeEnd( list.size() - 2 ) :  this will crash with the same read - write problem. Definetly bad solution

Comment: A thread-safe version of remove shouldn't throw, but return null.

Comment: I am not sure what a thread-safe version of remove(index) is good for. It's not like you have any chance of knowing for sure what's in index i. It might change between the time you though you knew what's there and the time you called to remove it.

Comment: @Shloim tell please more detail, it could be useful

Answer (score 0):

Your options are;

- expose the lock so it can be held during both options.
- use synchronized with a lock which is visable.
- add a removeLast() operation.
- add a drainTo() operation.
- use one of the built in thread safe collections which does this already.

It appears you want to drain N objects so the last option is likely to be best.

Comment: what if I will use other case, instead deleting last, could I avoid to write special methods for each case?

Comment: @jenius yes, you can implement your own drainTo() or just drain() which removes multiple elements at once.